# Can a change in Gradle plugin version affect APK performance?

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, gradle-plugin

I recently upgraded my Android application from using Gradle Plugin **2.2.3** to Gradle Plugin **3.0.1.** With these changes, my application has suffered from performance hits (under 1s, but noticeable) when starting activities, reloading views after a CursorLoader finishes, etc.

For example, in one scenario the user performs an action which queries the database and loads another screen. This time in milliseconds has changed from around 470ms to 1200ms. I feel that I should be troubleshooting why the delay would be this large in the first place, but my primary focus for now is how a gradle plugin version change would impact it at all.

I decided to narrow down the issue by upgrading only to **2.3.0**. The performance issues still exist. This is the *only* change in my project-level Gradle file necessary for me to reproduce slow behavior:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    ...
}
```

changes to...

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    ...
}
```

Build tools are consistently version 26.0.2. I've verified slowness on a device running Marshmallow and one running Lollipop. I noticed no difference on a device running Nougat.

1. Is it reasonable for me to say that a Gradle plugin versioning change is impacting the built APKs performance?
2. What other factors as a result of this one-line change could be at fault?
3. What other information can I give you to help point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I created a sample app that reproduced this behavior. It consists of two activities. The first one launches the second one when I press a button. The second activity performs a dummy *for* loop for a large amount of iterations, logging before and after timestamps.

MainActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
```

SecondActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SecondActivity:onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(TAG, "Before wait...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {

        }
        Log.i(TAG, "After wait...");
    }
```

Results:

***2.2.3:***
01-15 14:23:54.65 I/SecondActivity: SecondActivity:onCreate
01-15 14:23:54.705 I/SecondActivity: Before wait...
01-15 14:23:56.635 I/SecondActivity: After wait...
(2 seconds)

***2.3.0:***
01-15 14:25:25.185 I/SecondActivity: SecondActivity:onCreate
01-15 14:25:25.265 I/SecondActivity: Before wait...
01-15 14:25:55.795 I/SecondActivity: After wait...
(30 seconds)

Comment: The answer to the original question is no.  Gradle is a build system.  The apk it writes will not differ based on gradle version, and the output no longer depends on gradle.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It was silly of me in hindsight to expect this to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Preferences (Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run) and disabled Instant Run. My problems are solved. I guess I wasn't used to this feature existing after being on the old version for so long.

Closest I can find to an explanation is here:
https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f

> From now on, each time a method gets called — anywhere within our
>   app — the instrumentation injected into our original class files
>   communicates with the App Server to see if they’ve been updated.

For now I'm just going to stop bashing my head against the wall.